# Dynamic menu with Mongoid in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, algorithm, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I'm building Sinatra/Mongoid app and I want to create a dynamic menu of array values ​​in documents from MongoDB. I guess the following algorithm:
Supose in Mongo stored some documents

```
{ "name": "doc1", "array": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"] }
{ "name": "doc2", "array": ["foo", "baz"] }
{ "name": "doc3", "array": ["bar", "baz", "quux"] }
{ "name": "doc4", "array": ["quux"] }
{ "name": "doc5", "array": ["foo", "quux"] }
```

Now I guess it should

1. ask all docs for "array" field values,
2. then sort values in order of number of mentions,
3. delete duplicate values
4. and give me this new array to build `%ul` in my view, like so:

   ```
   %ul
     %li foo
     %li bar
     %li baz
     %li quux
   ```

And I've got no idea how to implement this.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand your problem. Can you add an HTML/HAML/whatever snippet with the desired output from example input above?

Comment: Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/VstFPk04)

Comment: I've incorporated your snippet into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you already have an `arrays` variable with the "array" values of your documents:

```
arrays = [
  ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"],
  ["foo", "baz"],
  ["bar", "baz", "quux"],
  ["quux"],
  ["foo", "quux"]
]
```

In this case, I'd use a Hash to store the array value as key, and a counter a value. This allows to

1. eliminate double entries, and
2. create a handle for sorting.

The interesting bit is the [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method, which iterates over an enumerable and *injects* an accumolator (`memo`):

```
list = arrays.flatten.inject({}) do |memo, e|
  memo[e] = (memo[e] || 0) + 1
  memo
end
#=> [["foo", 3], ["bar", 2], ["baz", 3], ["quux", 4]]
```

This creates this `list` which then can be sorted:

```
list = list.sort{|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1] }
#=> [["bar", 2], ["foo", 3], ["baz", 3], ["quux", 4]]
```

and filtered:

```
list = list.map(&:first)
#=> ["bar", "foo", "baz", "quux"]
```

You then can iterate over that array in your view.

---

N.B. I usually try to compress the `inject` call a little more, like so

```
list = arrays.flatten.inject({}) do |memo, e|
  (memo[e] ||= 0) += 1
  memo
end
```

or

```
list = arrays.flatten.inject(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=0 }) do |memo, e|
  memo[e] += 1
  memo
end
```

… but for some reason, my Ruby currently thinks that's an syntax error. Maybe it's just a lack of coffee ;-)